# Remove normals from vertex and fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application with OpenGL ES 2.0 stuff in C++.

Here are my vertex and fragment shader:

```
static const char* cubeMeshVertexShader = " 

attribute vec4 vertexPosition; 
attribute vec4 vertexNormal; 
attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord; 

varying vec2 texCoord; 
varying vec4 normal; 

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix; 

void main() 
{ 
   gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertexPosition; 
   normal = vertexNormal; 
   texCoord = vertexTexCoord; 
} 
";

static const char* cubeFragmentShader = " 

precision mediump float; 

varying vec2 texCoord; 
varying vec4 normal; 

uniform sampler2D texSampler2D; 

void main() 
{ 
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord); 
} 
";
```

I'm very new on OpenGL ES 2.0 development.

Someone told me that if I want lights on my render I have to make some complicates modification on vertex and fragment shader. So, I don't how to do that, normals are not necessary.

My question is:

How do I modify vertex and fragment shaders for not using normals?

Thanks

Comment: Your normal transformation code is incorrect anyway. Should be `normal = vec4(inverse(transpose(mat3(modelViewProjectionMatrix))) * vertexNormal.xyz, 0.0);` in a vertex shader.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way around using normals if you want to have lighting. I usually export the normals from my 3d package and use those, but you can always create them on the fly in your c++ code.
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/opengl/article.php/c2681

Comment: Thanks but I want to remove then from vertex and fragment shader. At this moment I don't want any lighting. I'm going to bake lights into textures.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question then. Why can't you just remove them? Afaik, if you don't declare the normals in your shader, it won't be used. You only have to remove the declaration (varying vec4 normal;) in both shaders and remove the normal attribute from the vertex shader (and of course that assignment). And make sure you pass only position and uv data from your c++ programm into opengl.